# Facelets custom component doesn't set attribute after submit

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I am having a problem with custom components in facelets.  The first time that the page is rendered, the attributes are set properly on the component class.  When a form is submitted however, the attributes are not set.

Here is the class that I am using to test this.

```
public class TestEcho extends UIData
{
    /** Logger. */
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestEcho.class);

    private String msg;

    public TestEcho()
    {
        log.debug("Constructor.");
    }

    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException
    {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("div", this);
        writer.writeText("The value of msg is '" + msg + "'.", null);
        writer.endElement("div");
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg)
    {
        log.debug("Setting msg to '" + msg + "'.");
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

The component is used in the .xhtml page like this.

```
<h:form>
    <v:testEcho msg="hello" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{PictureManager.trigger}" value="Click" />
</h:form>
```

When the page renders for the first time, the component renders the following html code.

```
<div>The value of msg is 'hello'.</div>
```

When the button is clicked, it renders this.

```
<div>The value of msg is 'null'.</div>
```

From the log, you can see that the component is constructed again, but the attribute is not set.

```
13:23:42,955 DEBUG [TestEcho] Constructor.
13:23:42,955 DEBUG [TestEcho] Setting msg to 'hello'.
----- Button was pressed here -----
13:25:48,988 DEBUG [TestEcho] Constructor.
13:25:49,144 DEBUG [PictureManager] Button pressed.
```

From what I understand, facelets does all the wiring of attributes to components so I don't need a tag class, but I don't understand why the attribute would be set correctly the first time, but not the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save your state by overriding the [saveState](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#saveState(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) and [restoreState](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#restoreState(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.Object)) methods.

So, *saveState* must return a [Serializable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) object (e.g. a JavaBean or Object[] array) containing the value in *msg* and whatever is returned by *super.saveState*. This object will be provided to *restoreState* where the method must restore *msg* from the object and pass the parent state to *super.restoreState*.

Answer (score 1):

McDowell's answer did it.  Just for completeness, here's the two methods I added.

```
public Object saveState(FacesContext context)
{
    Object[] rtrn = new Object[2];
    rtrn[0] = super.saveState(context);
    rtrn[1] = msg;
    return rtrn;
}

public void restoreState(FacesContext context, Object state)
{
    Object[] values = (Object[]) state;
    super.restoreState(context, values[0]);
    msg = (String) values[1];
}
```